# Expected Hamming distance of $a+b$ and $(a \oplus b) \oplus ((a \land b) \ll 1)$

Tags: hash

**Motivation.** In their [paper](https://www.aumasson.jp/data/papers/AJN14a.pdf) about the cryptographic scheme NORX, the authors use a fast approximation of + by bitwise operations (taking fewer CPU cycles than proper addition) using the formula $$a+b \; \approx \; a \oplus b \oplus ((a \land b) \ll 1)$$ where $\oplus$ is bitwise XOR and $\land$ is bitwise AND, and $\ll$ is left-shift by 1 position.  (The purpose of $((a \land b) \ll 1)$ is to simulate the "carry-bit" operation.) I am wondering "how well" this approximation works in terms of the expected value of the Hamming distance between $a+b$ and $a \oplus b \oplus ((a \land b) \ll 1).$

So let's make this more precise.

**Formal version.** Let $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ denote the collection of functions $f:\mathbb{N}\to \{0,1\}$ and let $$\{0,1\}^* = \{x \in \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}: \exists N\in\mathbb{N}(\forall k\in\mathbb{N}(k\geq N\implies x(k)=0))\}.$$
Every member of $\{0,1\}^*$ can be viewed as the binary expansion of a natural number; this is a unique correspondence. This correspondence gives rise to the addition $+:\{0,1\}^* \times \{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1\}^*$. Denote by $\ll 1$ the *left-shift* by one position, i.e. $$\ll 1 : x \in \{0,1\}^* \mapsto x'\in \{0,1\}^*$$ where $x'(0) = 0$ and $x'(n+1) = x(n)$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. We usually write $x \ll 1$ instead of $\ll 1(x)$.

For $x\in\{0,1\}^*$ we set $\text{len}(x) = \max\{k\in\mathbb{N}:x(k) = 1\}$.

For $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ we denote by $\text{diff}(a,b)$ the *[Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance)* between $a+b$ and $a \oplus b \oplus ((a \land b) \ll 1)$.

For a positive integer $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we let $$A_n = \frac{1}{2^{2n}} \sum\{\text{diff}(a,b): \text{len}(a), \text{len}(b) \leq n\}$$ be the average Hamming distance that $a+b$ has from $a\oplus b \oplus ((a \land b) \ll 1)$ when we limit the length of $a,b$ to at most $n$.

An [experiment](https://github.com/dominiczypen/plus_approximation/blob/main/plus_approx.c) seems to imply that $A_n \sim \log(n)$ as $n$ grows large.

**Question.** Does $(A_n / \log(n))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converge to a finite value?

Comment: Note that as $a+ b = (a\oplus b) \stackrel{(1)}{+} ((a\land b)\ll 1)$, the approximation can be seen to be an equality provided that $a,b\in\{0,1\}^n$ are such that one only needs to "propagate carries" once (meaning the operation marked (1) produces no carries). It seems plausible that counting the number of $(a, b)$ such that the operation marked (1) produces no carries is an exercise in simple combinatorics, but I don't have time to think about it right now.

Comment: I'm ready to bet the house on yes, and something on that limit being a simple fraction [update: when we take the log to base 2, of course... or how to loose a bet with self by insufficient attention to detail].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The NORX operation $a \oplus b \oplus (a \land b) \ll 1$, a simplification of the well-known identity $a + b = a\oplus b + (a \land b) \ll 1$ is essentially a parallel round of carry propagation.

The question here poses the question of what the average weight of $(a+b) \oplus (a \oplus b) \oplus (a \land b) \ll 1$. But this is directly related to computing how many more rounds of carry propagation would be necessary if one were to perform the addition as follows:
$$
a, b = (a \oplus b, (a\land b) \ll 1)
$$
until $b = 0$. This addition features in von Neumann's [report on the EDVAC](https://www.ias.edu/sites/default/files/library/Prelim_Disc_Logical_Design.pdf) (page 17), and has also been analyzed by [Knuth](https://doi.org/10.1016/1385-7258(78)90041-0), [Pippenger](https://doi.org/10.1006/jagm.2002.1216), and others.

The answer is that this number is the number of carry chains longer than $1$. The probability that a carry chain of length $l$ occurs is given by the event that the first pair of bits in the sequence is $(1,1)$, and the subsequent pairs are all either $(0, 1)$ or $(1, 0)$. This translates to a probability of $1/4 \times (1/2)^{l-1} = 2^{-(l+1)}$. Given there are $n - l + 1$ possible blocks of $l$ bits, the expected number of carry chains of length $l$ is $\frac{n-l+1}{2^{l+1}}$.

For the sake of Hamming weight, each carry chain at step $i$ contributes one bit to the total sum. Thus the total average weight will be the expected number of carry chains of length $2, 3, \dots, n$.

Now we have everything we need to obtain the solution. We consider all carry chain sizes except the ones of length $0$ and $1$, which are handled by the NORX operation. This gives us

$$
\sum_{i=2}^n \frac{n-i+1}{2^{i+1}} = \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{n-i+1}{2^{i+1}} - \sum_{i=0}^2 \frac{n-i+1}{2^{i+1}} = \frac{n-2}{4} + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\,.
$$
Because in modular addition the most significant bit does not propagate, we consider $n-1$ instead; in this case it becomes $\frac{n-3}{4} + \frac{1}{2^n}$.

Comment: Thanks to both poncho and Samuel for your answers; I am a bit unhappy that I cannot accept both answers...!

Comment: When you refer to "the well known identity $a \oplus b + (a \wedge b) \ll 1$", what are the two things that are identical?

Comment: Yeah, I guess there was something missing there. FIxed.

Answer (score 2):

If we actually run the search on various word sizes, we see that $A_n$ converges quite rapidly to either $(n-2)/4$ or $(n-3)/4$ (the former if the operations are taken on integers, the latter if the operation it taken modulo $2^n$).

Here are the values I got:

```
n=1: An(no modulo)=0.000000 An(modulo)=0.000000
n=2: An(no modulo)=0.125000 An(modulo)=0.000000
n=3: An(no modulo)=0.312500 An(modulo)=0.125000
n=4: An(no modulo)=0.531250 An(modulo)=0.312500
n=5: An(no modulo)=0.765625 An(modulo)=0.531250
n=6: An(no modulo)=1.007812 An(modulo)=0.765625
n=7: An(no modulo)=1.253906 An(modulo)=1.007812
n=8: An(no modulo)=1.501953 An(modulo)=1.253906
n=9: An(no modulo)=1.750977 An(modulo)=1.501953
n=10: An(no modulo)=2.000488 An(modulo)=1.750977
n=11: An(no modulo)=2.250244 An(modulo)=2.000488
n=12: An(no modulo)=2.500122 An(modulo)=2.250244
n=13: An(no modulo)=2.750061 An(modulo)=2.500122
n=14: An(no modulo)=3.000031 An(modulo)=2.750061
n=15: An(no modulo)=3.250015 An(modulo)=3.000031
n=16: An(no modulo)=3.500008 An(modulo)=3.250015
```

Comment: Addition: the answer is not 42. Poncho shows it's 1/4 when we take the log to base 2.